# both myForm.$valid & myForm.$invalid are undefined on angular form?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form named `myform` & I'm trying to set `ng-disabled` with this code:

```
ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
```

but both `myForm.$invalid` & `myForm.$valid` are undefined.  What is the issue exactly?  I checked in console & `myForm` is correctly set to the form.

**UPDATE**

```
 <form id="commissionForm" name="myForm" class="form-horizontal">

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8" />
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2" >
                    <button name="NextBtn" id="NextBtn"
                            ng-class="{disabled:commissionForm.$invalid}"
                            ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"
                            ng-click="nextBtnClicked()" class="btn btn-primary"
                            >Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Can you show more code? How did you define the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change 'myForm' to 'commisionForm' to make it work. Also, your form needs to have at least one element that binds to the model, using `ng-model`. Otherwise, validation will not fire.

Working code sample:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <form id="commissionForm" name="commissionForm" class="form-horizontal">
    <div>form $valid: {{commissionForm.$valid}}</div>
    <div>form $invalid: {{commissionForm.$invalid}}</div>
    <div>An input box with max length 5, to make the form invalid:</div>
    <input ng-maxlength="5" ng-model="somemodel"/>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xs-8" />
      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xs-2">
        <button name="NextBtn" id="NextBtn" ng-class="{disabled:commissionForm.$invalid}" ng-disabled="commissionForm.$invalid" ng-click="nextBtnClicked()" class="btn btn-primary">Next</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to utilize angular's built in form validation check out angular's documentation on the form directive:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
  userType: <input name="input" ng-model="userType" required>
  <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">Required!</span><br>
  <code>userType = {{userType}}</code><br>
  <code>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</code><br>
  <code>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</code><br>
  <code>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</code><br>
  <code>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</code><br>
 </form>
```

Take note that the form name attribute should map to the angular validation services. Looks like you didn't change that in your code.

myForm is `undefined` because according to your code the name of your form is `commissionForm` not `myForm`. From the code you provided.